# JavaScript: Why am I getting an undefined value while using random numbers from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, random, rounding

I am using Javascript to set a element's background image in from a class. The code works for the most part, but I get a undefined variable when I run the code. I am using Math.Random() to get the numbers for the variables. The problem point in my code (or at least I think it is):

```
var RandomContentDiv = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
var cd = RandomContentDiv[Math.round(Math.random()*RandomContentDiv.length-1)];
console.log(cd);
```

I put `console.log(cd);` to see what numbers are being outputted. I get results, but the results are not useful in solving the problem. I will test run the code 2 times to show you what I would typically get.

**Test 1:**

```
Number: 5
Number: 13
Number: 10
Number: 1
Number: 10
Number: 6
Number: 10
Number: 3
Number: 2
Number: 15
Number: 2
Number: 3
Number: 8
Number: 15
Number: 12
Number: 7
Number: 9
Number: 2
Number: 0
Number: 8
Number: 10
Number: 3
Number: 14
Number: 13
Number: 9
Number: 1
Number: 15
Number: 13
Number: 3
Number: 2
Number: 4
Number: 14
Number: 11
Number: 0
Number: 15
Number: 7
Number: 6
Number: 1
Number: 4
Number: 7
Number: 8
Number: 6
Number: 7
Number: 4
Number: 10
Number: 0
Number: 12
Number: 11
Number: 2
Number: 7
Number: 2
Number: 11
Number: 13
Number: 6
Number: 0
Number: 5
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 7
Number: 8
Number: 2
Number: 13
Number: 4
Number: 3
Number: 7
Number: 15
Number: 5
Number: 1
Number: 0
Number: 2
Number: 11
Number: 8
Number: 10
Number: 12
Number: 11
Number: 1
Number: 12
Number: 11
Number: 12
Number: 0
Number: 6
Number: 8
Number: 1
Number: 11
Number: 1
Number: 12
Number: undefined
```

**Test 2:**

```
Number: 13
Number: 2
Number: 9
Number: 0
Number: 2
Number: 0
Number: 11
Number: 3
Number: 5
Number: 3
Number: 11
Number: 3
Number: 14
Number: 15
Number: 9
Number: 8
Number: 11
Number: 12
Number: 10
Number: 3
Number: 9
Number: 0
Number: undefined
```

I think the problem is coming from this statement: `RandomContentDiv[Math.round(Math.random()*RandomContentDiv.length-1)];`, but I don't know how to fix it because I haven't dove deep enough in `Math` for JavaScript. All I know is that someone said something about `Math.Round` giving you an inaccurate number when rounded (i.e 1.5 could round to 1), but I don't think that it applies to this. Can anyone tell me if it is the statement that is causing the problem or something else?

Comment: Questions here shouldn't include "ALL" your code. You should reduce your code to the shortest example that reproduces your problem That said, `Math.random() * length - 1` is wrong. Your order of operations is incorrect, because `*` has higher precedence than `-`. Fix it by adding parenthesis so that the `-` happens before the `*`.

Comment: @meagar it is "Here is ALL of my Javascript code", and I will try your solution,

Comment: I know, and I'm telling you that including **all** your javascript code makes this question off topic. Your issue could be reproduced in a single three line loop, and that loop is what should be included. Nothing more.

Comment: @meagar What do I take out?

Comment: @meagar I think I took out the unnecessary code. Give it another look if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way you are calculating the index to the RandomContentDiv array.

Your code has this where you're getting the number that is coming out undefined in the console...

`cd = RandomContentDiv[Math.round(Math.random()*RandomContentDiv.length-1)];`

Sometimes Math.random() gives you a very small number close to zero, and that translates into you trying to access RandomContentDiv[-1], which is undefined.

Take a look at the example getRandomInt function at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random.  It is an example of how you should randomly select an integer between 0 and RandomContentDiv.length-1.

Comment: That's what I assumed the problem to be; however, I tried taking out the negative, and it still happened. Do you know how I can change that to make my code more accurate?

Comment: See the example I referenced. It shows how to generate a number from zero to N-1 which is what you want.

Comment: Someone suggested that the problem was my parentheses, so I changed it to `cd = RandomContentDiv[Math.round(Math.random()*(RandomContentDiv.length-1))];`, and it worked. Put that in your answer and I'll accept it.